# Rails app deploy on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, production-environment

I'm new in rails app development I am little bit confusing about rails deployment.

I following this guide below and done at all.
That mean my rails app on production mode?

Need to change Puma RACK_ENV to 'production' in Profile before pushing to heroku?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

Comment: Describe your problem so that the community can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe so. The entire tutorial is setting up your rails server to work in `production` mode. Using some inductive logic, it seems that the tutorial is assuming you're in production:

> "Rails 4 no longer has a static index page in production. When you’re
>   using a new app, there will not be a root page in production, so we
>   need to create one. We will first create a controller called welcome
>   for our home page to live:"

Indicates to me that it's assuming your rails server will be running in production.

To make doubly sure, you can check the `heroku logs` and look for a line that says:

`Rails [your version] application starting in production`

Comment: Need to change RACK_ENV to 'production' in Procfile before pushing to heroku?